# Cakephp dynamic homepage without slug

Tags: cakephp-3.0

I am trying to build a dynamic page system with cakephp 3.
Using slugs I can show pages and content. But on the homepage, it is just using the default view template.

I have the routes as followed:

```
$routes->connect('/', ['controller' => 'pages', 'action' => 'display', 'home']);
$routes->connect('/:slug', ['controller' => 'pages', 'action' => 'view'], ['pass' => ['slug'], 'slug' => '[^\?/]+']);
```

Which works for the none homepage pages.

But I want to use the homepage as / (e.g. localhost:8000/)

And not /home (e.g. localhost:8000/home).

Currently the view function in the pages controller looks like this:

```
public function view($slug = null) 
{
    $pages = TableRegistry::getTableLocator()->get('webpages');

    $page = $pages->findBySlug($slug)->firstOrFail();
    $this->set(compact('page'));
}
```

Any idea?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Seems I already found the solution.

I changed the routing to just the following line:

```
$routes->connect('/*', ['controller' => 'pages', 'action' => 'view']);
```

Then I changed the view as followed:

```
public function view($slug = null) 
{
    $pages = TableRegistry::getTableLocator()->get('webpages');
    if($slug == null){
        $query = $pages->find('all', [
            'conditions' => ['ishome' => 1]
        ]);
    } else {
        $query = $pages->find('all', [
            'conditions' => ['slug' => $slug]
        ]);
    }
    $page = $query->first();
    $this->set(compact('page'));
}
```

I use the answer from the following comment, but had to modify it a bit, since that code was used for an older version of cakephp (I am using cakekphp 3.8).

https://stackoverflow.com/a/3975923/6181243